# Infinity times minus one

Tags: calculus, infinity

Is the following statement mathematically correct:

$a = +\infty \iff -a = -\infty $

If so, it is the definition of $-\infty$? If not, is there a mathematical proof for it?

My knowledge in maths come from secondary school. I am currently brushing up on sequences.
I know that $\bar R$ is $R$ with $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, and that $+\infty$ is the bigger element of this set and $-\infty$ the smallest element of this set.
I want to know if it is correct to say: $$\forall a \in \{-\infty, +\infty \}, \forall l \in R^{*}_{-}, \{u_n \to l,  v_n \to a \} \implies (u v)_n \to -a$$

Comment: To have any hope of having a reasonable discussion on the topic... we must first ask and clarify what you know about $\infty$ in the first place... how it is formally defined... what context in which you are working.  Equally plausible answers could be 1) There is no such number as $\infty$, 2) There is such a number as $\infty$ and it is different than $-\infty$ and yes $-1\times \infty = -\infty$, or even 3) There is such a number as $\infty$ and it is the only such number.  $-1\times \infty = \infty$.

Comment: Those answers corresponding to the contexts being: 1) Real numbers (*the most common and arguably most useful everyday context*), 2) [Extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), 3) [Extended complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere).  The usefulness of discussing arithmetic in these which involve infinity varies on context.  There also exist other more exotic contexts which you could be alluding to as well which I will intentionally not mention.

Comment: Maybe $a \to \infty \iff -a\to -\infty$

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number. We do have that if $x_n$ converges to $\infty$ then $-x_n$ converges to $-\infty.$

Comment: I’ve added details to clarify the question.

Comment: You're reasoning in the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), which isn't wrong but also isn't compulsory. @ThomasAndrews has pointed you in an alternative direction, with the terminology "converges to $\pm\infty$". I think most mathematicians would prefer to say "_diverges_ to $\pm\infty$", but it comes down to how e.g. $x_n\to42$ (meaning if $n$ is sufficiently large $x_n$ is arbitrarily close to $42$) is very different in meaning from $x_n\to\infty$ (meaning if $n$ is sufficiently large $x_n$ is positive & arbitrarily large).

Comment: Instead of thinking in terms of algebraic operations on infinite values, I prefer to just keep in mind that $\lim a_n=\infty$ means $a_n$ diverges in the positive direction and $\lim a_n=-\infty$ means $a_n$ diverges in the negative direction. It's hard to make mistakes that way.